# Writing into partitioned Hive table takes longer as table grows

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs, parquet

I'm using Spark 2.4.4 to write into a 2-level partitioned external hive table (format parquet on HDFS):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable (<SCHEMA>)
PARTITIONED BY (`field1` STRING, `field2` STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
)
STORED AS
  INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/....
```

The schema is rather complex (many nested arrays and structs). As I'm inserting into that table:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto(myTable)
```

The time spent for IO increases with every job. Per job (batch of data) I'm writing into 5-10 different `field2` partitions (which are empty before the job). So I'm actually only appending data

Starting from an empty table, writing a batch of data takes several seconds (some GB of data), now the time has grown up to 30min (SparkUI shows all jobs are completed, so I assume it's IO which blocks the progress of the spark app). There are absolutely no logs written during this time, neider on executors nor on driver.

I assume that spark scans all existing partitions for each overwrite action... but I'm not sure.

I've  set `hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true`, and `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic`. The rest of the config is default.

Comment: Are you overwriting the table for every job? If so, what's the point of saving your data?

Comment: maybe it is Hive statistics auto gathering... Try set hive.stats.autogather=false;

Comment: @leftjoin good idea, but unfortunately did not help

Comment: @mck no I don't overwrite data. As I explained in the question, I'm writing (adding) new partitions with each job

Comment: @RaphaelRoth hmm, then try `.mode("append")`?

Comment: @mck You are right, `mode("append")` is much faster! I used mode `"overwrite"` because I sometimes re-process data and found it convenient to have the partitions overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the dataframe directly into the path where your partitioned data resides and this is the same path that is mentioned in the `CREATE TABLE` statement of Hive

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("col_specified_for_partitioning").parquet("/path/mentioned/in/create/table")

spark.sql("MSCK REPAIR TABLE dbname.tablename")
```

This should solve the case where you wish to drop and re-create the data for a certain partition and `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` simply makes the table aware of the partitions in the HDFS path.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
data.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("table")
```

You can also try the way @yayati-sule mentioned above to write the data, i.e, specifying the target directory directly as shown below,

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("parquet").partitionBy("field1", "field2").save("hdfs://nameservice1/user/raw/table/<YYYYMMDDHHMMSS>")
```

Also you can try setting the session conf too,

```
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
```

Or if that too fails, try the old fashioned way, and then do `alter table add partition`.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("hdfs://nameservice1/user/raw/table/field1=val1/field2=val2/")
```

Anyone using Pre Hadoop-3.3 and S3 using the [Hadoop_S3A_client](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Introducing_the_Hadoop_S3A_client.) there are  some performance improvements done later down the road. So upgrade.